# How to right align comments of an equation?

Tags: align, alignment, flalign

I want to right align (something like \raggedleft ?) the comments of each line. I am using \ \ \ \ which are not good. Please suggest me a better way to write this. Should I use splitting or anything?

```
\begin{align*}
        & \ \ \ Opt_\rho (i,j,M)\\
        &= \min_{\kappa \in Seg(i,j)} (Cost(\rho, \kappa, M))\\  
        &  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{[Comment for the line]}\\
        &= \min_{1\leq l\leq i} (\min_{\kappa' \in Seg(l,j)} (Cost(\rho,\kappa',M)))\\ 
        & \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{[Comment for another line]} \\
        &= \min_{1\leq l\leq i} (\min_{\kappa''[l:i] \in Seg(l,j)} (\max_{\iota'' \in 
            \kappa''[l:i]} (||Cost(\rho, \iota'')-M||)))\\ 
        & \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{[More Comments]} \\
        &= \min_{1\leq l\leq i} (\min_{\kappa''[l:i] \in Seg(l,j)} (\max (\max_{\iota'' \in \kappa''} (||Cost(\rho, \iota'')-M||)), &\\
        & \ \ \ ||Cost(\rho,[l:i])-M||))\\ 
        & \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{[This is a long long long long comment]} \\
        &= \min_{1\leq l\leq i} (\max (\min_{\kappa'' \in Seg(l,j-1)} (\max_{\iota'' \in \kappa''} (||Cost(\rho, \iota'')-M||))), &\\
        & \ \ \ ||Cost(\rho,[l:i])-M||)\\ 
        & \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{[Finally this comment]} \\
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Thanks. The reason for providing this is my equation is quite long and the comment cannot stay in the same line as the equation. That is why I need to use different line. And I also tried using \hfill* but that goes out of the page boundaries. I have edited the code.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document with your equations. Size of `\textwidth` is important at design of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion, without knowing more, would be to use a `flalign*` environment, which uses the maximum width available to it, and put the comments as the right aligned part of the next alignment group, more or less like so:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Opt}{Opt}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cost}{Cost}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Seg}{Seg}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}


\begin{flalign*}
        &\phantom{=\ } \Opt_\rho (i,j,M)\\
        &= \min_{\kappa \in \Seg(i,j)} (\Cost(\rho, \kappa, M)) &   \text{[Comment for the line]}\\
        &= \min_{1\leq l\leq i} (\min_{\kappa' \in \Seg(l,j)} (\Cost(\rho,\kappa',M))) & \text{[Comment for another line]} \\
        &= \min_{1\leq l\leq i} (\min_{\kappa''[l:i] \in \Seg(l,j)} (\max_{\iota'' \in 
            \kappa''[l:i]} (||\Cost(\rho, \iota'')-M||))) & \text{[More Comments]} \\
        &= \min_{1\leq l\leq i} (\min_{\kappa''[l:i] \in \Seg(l,j)} (\max (\max_{\iota'' \in \kappa''} (||\Cost(\rho, \iota'')-M||)), &\\
        &\phantom{=\ } ||\Cost(\rho,[l:i])-M||)) & \mathllap{\text{[This is a long long long long comment]}} \\
        &= \min_{1\leq l\leq i} (\max (\min_{\kappa'' \in \Seg(l,j-1)} (\max_{\iota'' \in \kappa''} (||\Cost(\rho, \iota'')-M||))), &\\
        &\phantom{=\ } ||\Cost(\rho,[l:i])-M||) & \text{[Finally this comment]} \\
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image: aligned equations with comments]

A couple additional things: the really long comment as is would have made the "column" for the notes too wide, so I used `\mathllap` to allow it to horizontally overlap parts of the equation; luckily the line it is applied to is not that long. If it were, you'd likely have to put that comment on its own line.

Also, I suggest using `\DeclareMathOperator` for things like "Cost" and "Opt" since full "words" in mathmode do not look right unless they handled in a different way.

As Zarko mentioned in the comments, what works best will be different for different sized pages, so this may not work in your actual use case without tweaking.

Comment: Additional suggestions: `\lVert` and `\rVert` instead of `||` for proper spacing, manual adjustment of delimiter size with `\bigl`, `Bigl`, `biggl`, etc. Also, `\text` should probably be `\textup` in the comments to avoid unexpected changes if the surrounding text has a different shape.

Comment: Thanks. I found this to be the most easiest and useful way to write.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution based on `\intertext` , with the content ragged left:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\Cost}{Cost}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\Opt}{Opt}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\Seg}{Seg}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
            & \Opt_\rho (i,j,M)\\
             & = \min_{\kappa \in \Seg(i,j)} (\Cost(\rho, \kappa, M)) \\[-3ex]
              \intertext{\raggedleft [From Eq. \ref{eq:opt}]}
            & = \min_{1\leq l\leq i} (\min_{\kappa' \in \Seg(l,j)} (\Cost(\rho,\kappa',M))) \\[-3ex]
            \intertext{[\raggedleft From Proposition \ref{prop:minmin}]}
            &= \min_{1\leq l\leq i} (\min_{\kappa''[l:i] \in \Seg(l,j)} (\max_{\iota'' \in
                \kappa''[l:i]} (\|\Cost(\rho, \iota'')-M\|))) \\[-2.5ex]
            \intertext{\raggedleft [Definition of $\Cost(\rho, \kappa''[l:i],M)$]}
            & = \min_{1\leq l\leq i} (\min_{\kappa''[l:i] \in \Seg(l,j)} (\max (\max_{\iota'' \in \kappa''} (\|\Cost(\rho, \iota'')-M\|)), \|\Cost(\rho,[l:i])-M\|)) \\[-2.5ex]
            \intertext{\raggedleft [Separating the last segment $[l:i]$]}
            & = \min_{1\leq l\leq i} (\max (\min_{\kappa'' \in \Seg(l,j-1)} (\max_{\iota'' \in \kappa''} (\|\Cost(\rho,
            \iota'')-M\|))), \|\Cost(\rho,[l:i])-M \|) \\[-2.5ex]
            \intertext{\raggedleft [From Proposition \ref{prop:minmax}]} \\
    \end{align*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With use of `mathtools` and `linegoal` packages. Since your equation are quite wide, I add `geometry` package for increase `\textwidth` size.

For equations are used `align*` and `split` environments. Long comments are written in `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cost}{Cost}
\DeclareMathOperator{\opt}{Opt}
\DeclareMathOperator{\seg}{Seg}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\norm}[1]\lVert\rVert{#1}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \MoveEqLeft
\opt_\rho (i,j,M)
    & = \min_{\kappa \in\seg(i,j)} (\cost(\rho, \kappa, M)) 
                        &&  \text{[From Eq. \ref{eq:opt}]}                          \\
    & = \min_{1\leq l\leq i} (\min_{\kappa' \in \seg(l,j)} (\cost(\rho,\kappa',M)))
                        &&  \text{[From Proposition \ref{prop:minmin}]}             \\
    & = \min_{1\leq l\leq i} (\min_{\kappa''[l:i] \in Seg(l,j)} 
            (\max_{\iota'' \in \kappa''[l:i]} (\norm{\cost(\rho, \iota'')-M} )))
                        &&  \text{[Definition of $\cost(\rho, \kappa''[l:i],M)$]}    \\
    \begin{split}
     & = \min_{1\leq l\leq i} (\max (\min_{\kappa'' \in Seg(l,j-1)}  
            (\max_{\iota'' \in \kappa''}\\
     &\qquad    (\norm{\cost(\rho, \iota'')-M} ))), \norm{\cost(\rho,[l:i])-M})
        \end{split}  &&  \parbox{\linegoal}{\raggedright
                                            [This is a very, very, very long comment in two lines]}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]